# How to clear all public variables?

Tags: vba, excel, reset

Is it possible to clear all public variables without the needs to define one by one. It is like you press reset button in VBA. Is there any kind of code to do that?

Comment: `End` is the equivalent of a hard reset.

Comment: Alternatively (though End is a much better solution) you can force an error. This would allow you to clear public variables, but without ending the routine. You could force an error by doing something like `Debug.Print 1/0` which would throw a divide-by-zero error.